# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException 5 in Quicksort

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort, out

I'm trying to implement a recursive Quicksort but when I always test it I get an index out of bounds error and I have no idea why :( Tried to debug it by printing some of the array values, and it prints weird stuff. I really have no idea why it prints this, because I checked everything and it normally never should go out of bounds :s

```
public void testQuicksort){
    Integer[] a = {5, 3, 2, 1, -2};
    Comparable[] aClone = a.clone();
    quickSort.sort(aClone);

public static void sort(Comparable[] a) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (a == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    sort(a, 0, (a.length - 1));     
}

private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int min, int max){
    if (max <= min) return;
    int right = part(a, min, max);
    sort(a, min, right - 1);
    sort(a, right + 1, max);
}

private static int part(Comparable[] a, int min, int max){
    int left = min, right = max + 1;
    Comparable v = a[min];
    // printing v prints stuff like this:   
       "gna.TechnicalTests$IntBox@5dbbdd9b"

    while (true) {
        // exception in the first while loop
        while ((a[++left].compareTo(v) < 0)) if (left == max) break; 
        while ((v.compareTo(a[--right]) < 0)) if (right == min) break;
        if (left >= right) break;
        Comparable z = a[left];
        a[left] = a[right];
        a[right] = z;
    }
    Comparable y = a[min];
    a[min] = a[right];
    a[right] = y;
    return right;
}
```

Comment: And *where* did you get the exception?

Comment: Ow sorry forgot the most important thing :p I edited it

Comment: Ideally, package it up into a short but complete program so we can test it for ourselves, too. What version of Java are you using? I suspect that with a normal JVM, you'll get more sensible output...

Comment: I'm using jdk1.8 in eclipse and the test are run in JUnit

Comment: Odd. Printing v works fine for me (just prints the integers) and I don't get any exception with the code you've given.

Comment: Hmm weird, maybe their is something wrong with my Eclipse because I just ran it via the terminal with apache ant and I also don't get any exceptions :s